# Process returned 139 (0x8B) Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, sfml

I got the following problem:

I'm somewhat new to C++, looked up how to make multidimensional arrays without predefinition of size, I found something and tried it. I got a Process returned 139 (0x8B) as an answer. I looked up everything I found about it but It didn't help me at all.

My system: Linux Mint 64 Bit, Editor: Code::Blocks and Clion

Project: https://github.com/blueburningcoder/AntWorld.git

essential code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;


/*
 * Tile: the background is out of tiles
 *
 * setSize:
 * @param x: X-location of the Tile later on
 * @param y: Y-location of the Tile later on
 * @param height2: the height of the tile
 * @param width2: the width of the tile
 * (the 2 is there since the scope resolution operator didn't work for some reason)
 * setting the size, position and color of the rect
 *
 *
 * drawTile:
 * @param renderWindow: the window the rect is drawn in
 * drawing the rect
 */
class Tile {

    private:
        int locX, locY, height, width;
        //
        RectangleShape rect;

    public:
        void setSize(int x, int y, int height2, int width2){
            locX = x;
            locY = y;
            height = height2;
            width = width2;
            rect.setSize(Vector2f(height, width));
            rect.setFillColor(Color::Blue);
            rect.setPosition(Vector2f(locX, locY));
        }
        void drawTile(RenderWindow *renderWindow){
            renderWindow->draw(rect);
        }

};


/*
 * Maze: including all the Tiles, used to manipulate only specific Tiles
 * @param xSize: how many tiles are gonna be in x direction
 * @param ySize: how many tiles are gonna be in y direction
 *
 * drawMaze:
 * @param renderWindow: needed for the Tile.drawTile method to draw on
 * drawing all Tiles in the MAP
 */
class Maze {

    private:
        int sizeX = -1, sizeY = -1;
        vector<vector<Tile> > MAP;

    public:
        Maze(int xSize, int ySize){
            sizeX = xSize;
            sizeY = ySize;
            for(int i = 0; i < xSize; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < ySize; j++){
                    Tile tile;
                    tile.setSize(i * 35, j * 35, 30, 30);
                    // tile might not have been initialized?
                    MAP[i][j] = tile;
                }
            }
        }
        void drawMaze(RenderWindow *renderWindow){
            // TODO: draw Tiles!
            for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++){
                    MAP[i][j].drawTile(renderWindow);
                }
            }
        }
};



int main()
{
    // Create the main window
    RenderWindow app(VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

    // Load a sprite to display
    Texture texture;
    cout << "there's no error yet..." << endl;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("cb.bmp")) {
        cout << "failed to load!" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    Sprite sprite(texture);

    cout << "creating the maze ..." << endl;

    // Creating a 10 x 10 Maze
    Maze maze(10, 10);

    // Start the game loop
    while (app.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event event;
        while (app.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // Close window : exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                app.close();
        }

        cout << "gonna draw it ..." << endl;

        // Clear screen
        app.clear();

        // Draw the sprite
        app.draw(sprite);

        // drawing the Maze
        maze.drawMaze(&app);

        // Update the window
        app.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

correct answer below

Comment: Don't link to an external size if you are expecting someone to help you. And try to trim down the requirements for running the project. (Remember, good questions and answers are supposed to help other people in the future, and for that you need a "constant" content, not a link to a github page that may have 1000 more changes to it when someone tries to find the same answer in 4 years time)

Comment: Yeah you are right about that, I should have known better ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert into a `std::vector` just via indexing, you need to call the appropriate constructor which allocates a fixed amount of space.

```
std::vector<int> array(4);
// array[0 ... 3] are now accessible.
```

So your declaration should be like this :

```
MAP = std::vector<std::vector<Tile>>(xSize, std::vector<Tile>(ySize));
// now access MAP[i][j] 
// It basically reads, MAP has xSize number of elements where each defaults to a std::vector<Tile>(ySize).
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/11XMKJ) is an example.

Comment: suggest using a different wording than "reserve", to avoid confusion with what the `reserve()` member function does